# change the path of a file in folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
file_path = path.relpath(file_path_images)
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        splitLine = line.split(' ')
        ls.append(splitLine[1].strip())
        img.append(splitLine[0])
```

when

```
print(img[0:10])
```

I get:

```
['./2425/1/115_Lube_45484.jpg',
 './2425/1/114_Spencerian_73323.jpg',
 './2425/1/113_accommodatingly_613.jpg',
 './2425/1/112_CARPENTER_11682.jpg',
 './2425/1/111_REGURGITATING_64100.jpg',
 './2425/1/110_savannas_67969.jpg',
 './2425/1/109_unfix_82473.jpg',
 './2425/1/108_CAGOULES_10765.jpg',
 './2425/1/107_TRANSITS_80259.jpg',
 './2425/1/106_looped_45230.jpg']
```

now I want to read my images:

```
for image in img:
     image=cv2.imread(image)
```

However I need to update the path and replace `'.'` by `'/home/Downloads/mnt/ramdisk/max/90kDICT32px'` to get the path as follows:

```
'/home/Downloads/mnt/ramdisk/max/90kDICT32px/2425/1/115_Lube_45484.jpg'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
abspaths = [os.path.join('/home/Downloads/mnt/ramdisk/max/90kDICT32px',relpath) for relpath in img]
for image in abspaths:
     image=cv2.imread(image)
```